# AWS ECS Task: Mounting a volume to my container clears my copied file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, amazon-ecs

I am attempting to run a task with persistent storage. The task executes a docker image which creates a directory and copies a file into it. However, when the task definition mounts a volume to the created directory, the file is lost.

For brevity, the relevant lines Dockerfile are:

```
RUN mkdir /root/createdDir
COPY ./myFile.txt /root/createdDir/myFile.txt
```

And the relevant fields of the task definition JSON are:

```
{
  "containerDefinitions":[
  {
    ...,
    "mountPoints": [
      {
        "readOnly": null,
        "containerPath": "/root/createdDir",
        "sourceVolume": "shared"
      }
    ],
    "image": "myImage"
  }]
  "volumes": [
  {
    "name": "shared",
    "host": {
      "sourcePath": null
    }
  }]
}
```

When the task is run, the file can no longer be found. If I run the task without adding a mount point to the container, the file is still there.

When trying to do this locally using `docker-compose`, I can use the same `Dockerfile` and in the `docker-compose.yml` file add the following specification to the service volumes: `shared:/root/createdDir`, where shared is a volume also declared in the `docker-compose.yml` with a local driver.

Answer (score 3):

The behavior of mounting a volume into an existing directory on the container can be confusing. It is consistent with the general behavior of Linux's [mount](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount):

> The previous contents (if any) and owner and mode of dir become invisible.

Avoid doing this whenever possible, because it can lead to hard-to-find issues when the volume and the container have files with same names.